# define a route config file on bottle

Tags: python, model-view-controller, bottle

been playing with https://github.com/salimane/bottle-mvc example.  i'm trying to extract routes just to a file and defs similar to the controllers folder.  what i'm trying to simulate is the Ruby on Rails routes/controller behaviour.

in order to achieve that i first did this

app/controllers/print.py

```
def index(something=''):
    return template('printer/index', message='')
@app.route('/', method='GET',callback=index)


@app.route('/print', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def printer():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from project.models.Printer import Printer
        printer = Printer()
        message = printer.show_string(request.forms.get('text'))
        return template('printer/index', message=message)
    return template('printer/print', message='')
```

i did the "something=''" cuz python give me errors on running the server. saying

```
TypeError: index() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

after that little trick, server runs and everything works fine.

then i did the same with /print route:

app/controllers/print.py

```
def index(something=''):
    return template('printer/index', message='')
@app.route('/', method='GET',callback=index)


def printer(something=''):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from project.models.Printer import Printer
        printer = Printer()
        message = printer.show_string(request.forms.get('text'))
        return template('printer/index', message=message)
    return template('printer/print', message='')

@app.route('/print', method=['GET', 'POST'], callback=printer)
```

with this python error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

point to last line (EOF).  tested various combinations but i'm stuck.

OS X 10.9, Bottle 0.11.6, python 2.7

---

EDIT:

i think i didn't explain myself.

what i want, is something like this:

app/config/routes.py

```
@app.route('/', method='GET', callback=index)
@app.route('/print', method=['GET', 'POST'], callback=printer)
```

app/controllers/print.py

```
def index(something=''):
    return template('printer/index', message='')

def printer(something=''):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from project.models.Printer import Printer
        printer = Printer()
        message = printer.show_string(request.forms.get('text'))
        return template('printer/index', message=message)
    return template('printer/print', message='')
```

the "something" parameter was a workaround to make it work, cuz python gave me errors.

i can't separate routes from defs...that's the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  Basically, you just need to call `route` as a function, not a decorator.  (Remove the "@")

So, if you define your logic in `funcs.py`:

```
from bottle import template, request, Bottle

def index(something=''):
    return template('printer/index', message='')

def printer(something=''):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from project.models.Printer import Printer
        printer = Printer()
        message = printer.show_string(request.forms.get('text'))
        return template('printer/index', message=message)
    return template('printer/print', message='')
```

then this is how your main program would attach callbacks:

```
import bottle
import funcs

app = bottle.Bottle()

app.route('/', method='GET', callback=funcs.index)
app.route('/print', method=['GET', 'POST'], callback=funcs.printer)

app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

---

When I run `python routes.py`, it works as expected:

```
% 12:44:32 ~/>curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/print
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</title>
            ...
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</h1>
            <p>Sorry, the requested URL <tt>&#039;http://127.0.0.1:8080/print&#039;</tt>
               caused an error:</p>
            <pre>Template &#039;printer/print&#039; not found.</pre>
        </body>
    </html>
```

(HTTP 500 because template not found, but the point is that it ran `funcs.printer()`.)

Comment: it didn't work for me. gave me 404 error.  even when i did not use template, i used "<p>hello</p>" and it didn't work too.  also i run like 'python runserver.py' (i used like the link said).

Comment: Okay... I literally just copied my two code blocks, ran them, and it worked as expected (HTTP 500).  Like you, I'm on OSX 10.9, bottle 0.11.6, Python 2.7.  Are you sure you copied my code exactly, didn't modify it, and called it the same as my `curl` example?

Answer (score 1):

@app.route is a function decorator, so it should be used like this:

```
@app.route('/', method='GET')
def index(something=''):
    ...

@app.route('/print', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def printer(something=''):
    ...
```

check here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/